# Initialize const multidimensional array in class initializer list from constructor arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that includes a const 2d array of values, and I want to define this array when I call the constructor. I have been told using `const` on values that should never be changed is preferred, so I wanted to try it in this case.

```
class A {
  public:
    A(const int passedArray[2][2]) : memberArray(passedArray) {}
  private:
    const int memberArray[2][2];
};

const int passedArray[][2] = {
  {0,0},
  {0,1}
};

A a(passedArray); // fails with "incompatible types
                  //in assignment of 'const int (*)[2]' to 'const in[2][2]'
A a(&passedArray); // fails
```

This also fails with `const int passedArray[2][2] = ...`, with `private: const int** memberArray`, etc.

I know I have to use an initializer list because a constructor cannot change values of const. Is this possible at all on C++11?

Comment: You cannot pass arrays by value, and you cannot copy-initialize arrays. You could however initialize the array element by element: `: memberArray{{rhs[0][0], ... }}` Or use `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>` and be done.

Comment: Using `const` on class members is generally a poor idea IMO

Comment: @M.M Exactly the opposite... you should always make member constant if you never modify them except for initialisation.

Comment: You might embed the array in a structure if you want easy copying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to your question has some good info.

After that here is the working code:

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

class A {

  public:
    A(int passedArray[2][2]) 
    {
        //USE STD COPY TO COPY THE ARRAYS. 
        std::copy(&passedArray[0][0], &passedArray[0][0]+4,&memberArray[0][0]);

        //PRINT VALUES TO TEST
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                std::cout << memberArray[i][j] << std::endl;
            }           
        }
    }

  private:
    int memberArray[2][2];
};

int main()
{

     //INITIALIZE YOUR ARRAY
     int passedArray[2][2] = {
       {0,0},
       {0,1}
     };

     //CREATE OBJECT
     A a(passedArray); 
}
```

If your business need is to have a "const multi dimensional array in your class"
you have to do it any one of the below ways.

```
class A {

  public:
    A(const int passedArray[2][2]) 
    {

    }

  private:
    const int memberArray[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};   //INITIALIZE HERE
};
```

OR

```
class A {

  public:
    A(const int passedArray[2][2]) 
    {

    }

  private:
    //DECLARE STATIC HERE
    static const int memberArray[2][2];
};

//INTIALIZE HERE
const int A::memberArray[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};
```

Comment: Thank you. I need multiple instances of this class so a static const (or one initialized in the class without reading an argument) will not work for me. I think I will just have it as a private member array and not have it be const, even though it would be more correct that way.